# How to change custom keychain password programmatically using Keychain Services?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I used the [Keychain Services API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/keychain_services) to create a **new, custom keychain** in a file using `SecKeychainCreate()`. One argument to this function is the password for the keychain itself.

There are many functions that manipulate the *items* in the keychain, but I can't seem to find any function that allows changing the keychain's password.

Is there such a function, a technique outside of Keychain Services to change the password of a custom-created, non-default keychain?

The best I have been able to come up with is exporting all the items, creating a new keychain with the new password, then importing all the items. This seems ridiculous.

Comment: Why can't you use SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData() to update the password?

Comment: @rocky: `SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData()` changes the password of an item in a keychain. I'm looking to change the password of the keychain that _contains_ several items.